# Type narrowing with throw

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a function that can handle two mutually exclusive return types.  What am I misunderstanding about how typescript works?

```
type SuccessResponse<T> = { data: T; error: null };
type ErrorResponse<E> = { data: null; error: NonNullable<E> };
type Command<T, E> = () => ErrorResponse<E> | SuccessResponse<T>;

const myFunc = <T, E>(c: Command<T, E>): T => { 
  const result = c();
  if (result.error !== null) throw result.error;
  return result.data;
}
```

I get the following error on return:

```
Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | null'.(2322)
```

I can't just test `if (result.data)` because it is acceptable for `T` to be `null`.

---

Here is a longer example that explains the motivation for wanting the error type: So that a utility can assert and store it for later use.  (Imagine that neither `makeRefreshable` nor `myCommand` are under my control)

```
type SuccessResponse<T> = { data: T; error: null };
type ErrorResponse<E> = { data: null; error: NonNullable<E> };
type Command<T, E> = () => Promise<ErrorResponse<E> | SuccessResponse<T>>;

const myCommand = async () => {
  if (Math.random() < .1) return {data: null, error: new Error('Random error')};
  return await { data: Math.random(), error: null};
}

const getCommandResult = async <T, E>(c: Command<T, E>): Promise<T> => {
  const result = await c();
  if (result.error !== null) throw result.error;
  return result.data;
}

const makeRefreshable = <T, E>(f: () => Promise<T>) => {
  const result: {
    data: T | null;
    error: E | null;
    run: () => void;
  } = {
    data: null,
    error: null,
    run: () => {},
  }

  result.run = async () => {
    try {
      result.data = await f();
    } catch (err) {
      result.data = null;
      result.error = err as E;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const main = async () => {
  const result = makeRefreshable<number, Error>(() => getCommandResult(myCommand));
  await result.run();
  if (result.data) console.log(result.data);
  if (result.error) console.log(result.error.message);
  await result.run();
  if (result.data) console.log(result.data);
  if (result.error) console.log(result.error.message);
}

main();
```

Comment: Control flow and generic type parameters don't play nicely together; I'm not sure why you want your function to care about `E` though, since `throw`s don't keep track of the type they throw (certainly you can't `catch` anything but `any` and `unknown`).  You might as well just have the function accept `Command<T, unknown>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5QD0N).  If that fully addresses the question I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to show a use case where a generic `E` is needed.

Comment: I would also add that the compiler's happy if you check `data` for `null` instead of error; also hard coding `c` to `c: Command<T, string>`, for example, makes the error go away. It's got something to do with the fact that `E` is generic that it doesn't like.

Comment: @Richiban That won't work for them because they stated it is acceptable for `T` itself to be `null` while not being an error response. Your other suggestion does work though for reasons jcalz mentioned above.

Comment: @jcalz in my actual situation, myFunc captures the error and stores it for later use, so it's useful to be able to specify the error type.

Comment: Okay, please [edit] with at least a toy example of this, so that we can play around with it.

Comment: @jcalz I've edited to include a longer example.

Comment: Thanks! ① Your example has an error at `makeRefreshable<number, Error>(() => getCommandResult(myCommand))` that I don't think you're asking about. Could you clear that up so it's not a distraction?

Comment: ② If I replace your version with mine, I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6Q0YW), which doesn't seem any worse. I was hoping your example would demonstrate why `getCommandResult()` would need to be generic in `E`.  Your `getCommandResult()` return type still doesn't depend on `E`, so there's no obvious reason for `E` there.  Could you show an example where this matters? Or is it possible that it *doesn't* matter as I originally suggested? Either way is fine, just trying to figure out how to proceed here.

Comment: Updated so that we `console.log(error.message)`; we really are expecting type Error.  I guess your point is that if we are doing a type assertion anyway, it doesn't matter that we call it unknown before that.  Is that correct?

As far as the other error, isn't that the same issue?  It thinks `getCommandResult` returns `Promise<T|null>`, but it will always return `Promise<T>` as long as it doesn't throw.

Comment: Type assertion where, inside `makeRefreshable`? Yes, there is no such thing as "typed `throw`/`catch`" in TypeScript ([intentionally so](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219#issuecomment-1515037604)), so `getCommandResult()` does not depend on `E` at all, and even if it did it wouldn't help you with `catch`ing it.  The other error is not really the same issue; it's an inference thing; you can manually specify it is `number` instead of `number | null` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAPGvN) and it goes away. So how should we proceed? Shall I write an answer saying this?

Comment: Yes, go ahead, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't support a `throws` clause (as in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6)), so there's no way for the type system to express the idea that a function throws an error of a specified type.  That is, you can't say something like `declare function myFunc(): void throws MyError`.

Nor is there a way to only `catch` an exception of a particular expected type, since [`catch` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) will catch whatever is thrown and an unexpected error could occur.  If you write `try { myFunc() } catch (err: MyError) { }`, it is quite likely that `err` at runtime could be something completely different from `MyError`.  It's not like the `catch` clause will be skipped in such a case.  So even if you could annotate functions with `throws` clauses they wouldn't be very helpful when `catch`ing.

There was a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#13219](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219) to support `throws` and typed `catch` clauses, but it was ultimately declined.  If you're interested there is a [very thorough comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219#issuecomment-1515037604) detailing exactly why it was declined.  The upshot is that checked exceptions doesn't really fit in with the JavaScript language and ecosystem, and adding it to TypeScript would introduce more problems than it would purport to solve.

---

So, that means there really is no point in having `getCommandResult()` be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `E`, the error type thrown.  The return type of `getCommandResult()` is `Promise<T>`, with no mention of `E`, and the out-of-band information that you expect to catch errors of type `E` isn't anything the compiler can guarantee or track.

And therefore you might as well just replace `E` with `unknown`, for all the good it does you:

```
const getCommandResult = async <T,>(c: Command<T, unknown>): Promise<T> => {
  const result = await c();
  if (result.error !== null) throw result.error;
  return result.data;
}
```

Now there's no error in the implementation.

The issue when `E` is generic is that the compiler cannot do arbitrary analysis on generic types; while it seems obvious to us that a null `error` property should narrow a `ErrorResponse<E> | SuccessResponse<T>` to `SuccessResponse<T>`, that requires the compiler inspect the structure of `ErrorResponse<E>`... but when `E` is generic the compiler unfortunately gives up before it gets that far, and leaves `ErrorResponse<E>` mostly opaque when it comes to narrowing.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#55036](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55036) asking for an improvement, but for now it's not implemented.  If you *needed* `E` to be generic, we'd have to work around it.

But since there's no point in having `E` be generic, we might as well just use `unknown` and benefit from [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).

---

Anyway, when you call it `getCommandResult()`, you will need to check inside the `catch` block whether or not `err` is the type you expected, for the reasons mentioned above.  There's no way around that, unfortunately:

```
class MyError extends Error {
  timestamp: Date = new Date();
  constructor(msg: string) {
    super(msg)
  }
}

const myCommand: Command<number, MyError> = async () => {
  if (Math.random() < .1) return { data: null, error: new MyError('Random error') };
  return await { data: Math.random(), error: null };
}

async function foo() {
  try {
    const result = await getCommandResult(myCommand);
    console.log("SUCCESS: " + result)
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof MyError) {
      console.log("ERROR AT: " + err.timestamp.toString())
    } else {
      console.log("UNEXPECTED ERROR: " + err) // ‍♂️
    }
  }
}
foo(); // "SUCCESS: 0.9875369808095005" 
foo(); // "ERROR AT: Tue Dec 05 2023 20:49:51 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)" 
foo(); // "SUCCESS: 0.11642966130918875"
```

This is about as good as it gets.  The check for `MyError` must take place at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAzigSqsB7AdiiAHgBUA+KAXigG8oATAQ2AYC4piBuKCAJx+x5tccADYioAXw4AoUJCgBRPgMwoc+IgvJVajZkNEiuvfoKgA5POcMMARiM3kps8NADC2ALaeGuOiQAaRW0oAAoASkpyAAV+TwBLAkIlU1V1JK0oAB9YRGQ0NLwkslIZaWkEIuAoAHMIYA9vXzpVUWqqBhQQXAQoQNJQhDZGnz9AqDhcAGtcbAB3XFJwtlivRKIyKJppKChK-GqeVDbKKAY5hnjqhAiZXfiAMzCjlDaAOhMBKABCCiphMSRYAAC34cygL3enx4dwh9TgPFwcNeImAbz0DBkEnKCBEnRQUAAsiAUl8IAAPYAQPwE0k8ba7YDxTyoZieMBsAAiTGg-wg4O5VNuOz2VR4iGAAlCnhQNTYKGAPHiuBqkWoIt2r0gPGlsvCIux2IqVSgnhAI2awy8o38wk8tl4QWJdJCnW6vQiW3V9yeoUJTGBbx4zS8nsIUDeAEZIkdgAikbomKwoACREFoUJ+USScodQBydAhzzcXN5yLOXax+NnC5XGj0JNsf0goNFiLp3MGMSSLHlN09KAPSYIJl4QfYbCe71QRUgBm7UUHZEnDq16p1BrW5qtVHS81bvzhWG7fYobAON4ibA1UIAIhgAFU3G4FDAYGxb1AANTL1H63YSHsTAIMCYQmGqGpQI8YF8FBBy+Mg2BPM6uYQQuC6nueECXted4KOg6AAPLoFAACCxAft+JY8G8TIsgqDDsrR2AwIqyo3uE-4LoBEAiAQ87oZhF5Xjet4PuYCgABrRAobjEAonKKARxGUT+4FQAA9BpUCAHwbgDsu4AsASAEJkgDwf5B2IAdI2IPBOtyadp95Pi+b5sAADG8ACcAAcADsACsADMABs3muV5rkeX5rmuX5n7SDZk5HvZUC3vhREkeRbDEHA0CchAvQxVAABMrlFQFxWuSwAAsHksH5kZQAA4oSxAALSuUF0VhG41KKgw4isc0DA8HQ7DMhA4RxQldlaSlj7Pq+75QO5kaRkFVVFR5QVBZGAURZGXm+bFUDSEAA)

Comment: I don't totally get why `if (result.error !== null)` doesn't function as a type guard in my example, but in yours it seems to.  Why does it matter if it's `unknown` or any other type?

Comment: I edited the answer to explain that, let me know if you need anything else